# how to filter data start date end date basis in array mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

how to write query start date and end date basis,in `outdoor_tracking` there is column `tracking_created_date` , i want filter my all record start date  `tracking_created_date`   and end date `tracking_created_date`  filter all records in tracking column basis, please help me this. thanks

> i want filter my data tracking_created_date

```
export function getdatewise(req, res) {

  return Campaign.find({$or: [{ "assets.outdoor_tracking.tracking_created_date" : {"$gte":new Date(), "$lte": new Date()} }]  }).exec()
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Mongodb data

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a266f16663eb423d86937c9"),
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5a102c4b6b8d184b0897d4fc"),
            "brand_id" : ObjectId("5a102c726b8d184b0897d4ff"),
            "companyname" : "abc",
             "assets" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1ffdb68a624329a8196ec5"),
                    "city" : "abc",
                    "region" : "abc",
                    "location" : "abc",
                     "outdoor_tracking" : [ 
                        {
                          "latitude" : "1.192618",
                            "longitude" : "1.191406",
                             "_id" : ObjectId("5a266fadd5a1fe0dc053faee"),
                            "updated_date" : ISODate("2017-12-05T10:06:37.611Z"),
                            "tracking_created_date" : ISODate("2017-12-05T10:06:37.611Z"),
                            "comment" : "vfff"
                                   }
                    ]
                }
            ],"__v" : 1
        }
```

Comment: `"$lt": new new Date()` is that possible? Also, please edit the question to make it more clearer.

Comment: i want fatch all collection record  tracking_created_date basis , like start date in collection 02/12/2017 to 12/012/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally query created:

```
export function getdatewise(req, res) {

  return Campaign.find({$or: [{ "assets.outdoor_tracking.tracking_created_date" :  {$gte:new Date("2015-04-14T23:59:59Z"),$lte: new Date("2017-12-15T23:59:59Z")} }]  }).exec()
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```